# How do I use std::is_integral<> to select an implementation?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits

I'm trying to return an `int64_t` if `std::is_integral<>::value` is true.

Otherwise, I would like to call `to_int64t()` on the object.

My attempt below is failing because partial specialisation of function templates are not allowed.

**CODE**

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<class T,bool is_integral_type>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
        return t;
}

template<class T>
int64_t to_int64t<T,std::is_integral<T>::value>( const T& t )
{
        return t;
}

template<class T>
int64_t to_int64t<T,!std::is_integral<T>::value>( const T& t )
{
        return t.to_int64t();
}

int main()
{
        int64_t i = 64;
        auto x = to_int64t( i );
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073689/c11-template-function-specialization-for-integer-types

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Function templates cannot be partially specialized and, in general, it is not a good idea to use function template specialization.

One way to achieve what you want is to use a technique called *tag dispatching*, which basically consists in providing a forwarder function that selects the right overload based on the value of an extra dummy argument:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<class T>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t, std::true_type )
{
    return t;
}

template<class T>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t, std::false_type )
{
    return t.to_int64t();
}

template<class T>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
    return to_int64t(t, std::is_integral<T>());
}

int main()
{
    int64_t i = 64;
    auto x = to_int64t( i );
}
```

Another possibility is to use the classical SFINAE technique based on `std::enable_if`. This is how that could look like (notice that, since C++11, default template arguments on function templates are allowed):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
    return t;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<
    !std::is_integral<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
    return t.to_int64t();
}

int main()
{
    int64_t i = 64;
    auto x = to_int64t( i );
}
```

Yet another possibility, although more verbose, is to define helper class templates (which can be partially specialized) in a `detail` namespace and provide a global forwarder - I would not use this technique for this use case, but I am showing it because it might come handy in related design situations:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>

namespace detail
{
    template<class T, bool = std::is_integral<T>::value>
    struct helper { };

    template<class T>
    struct helper<T, true>
    {
        static int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
        {
            return t;
        }
    };

    template<class T>
    struct helper<T, false>
    {
        static int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
        {
            return t.to_int64t();
        }
    };
}

template<class T>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
    return detail::helper<T>::to_int64t(t);
}

int main()
{
    int64_t i = 64;
    auto x = to_int64t( i );
}
```

Comment: Oh my, this is beautiful. :)

Comment: Does the second one compile for you ? I get error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template

Comment: @Alon: Default template arguments on function templates where introduced with C++11, so you should compile with the `std=c++11` option (you may have to upgrade your compiler to the latest version if this is not supported)

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that is only available in gcc (Im using VS)

Comment: @Alon: OK, if you are using VS then you would need VS2012. Anyway you could make that default template argument a default *function* argument, which is less elegant but would still work

Comment: @AndyProwl: I am using 2012 and it still does not compile; what do you mean? move it from template signature to function signature second parameter? then the user has to type it ?

Comment: @Alon: Hm, then it looks like VS2012 support is still pretty limited. Yes, that's what I meant, and no, the user shall *not* type it, because it has a default value (`= nullptr`). The problem with this version is that the user *could* type it, which is not desirable. As long as the user will only pass one argument, however, this will work as intended.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Also, any chance you show an example of how to put it in the function arguments?

Comment: @AndyProwl: could you explain the compiler? if the enable_if failes it just doesn't select this function?

Comment: @Alon: Yes, that's called SFINAE (Substitution Failure Is Not An Error): the compiler tries to instantiate the function template's signature, and if it fails, it just discards the corresponding function from the overload set and considers only the other viable functions.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Both 1 and 3 are tag dispatching. 1 being tag dispatching by instance, while 3 being tag dispatching by type. ~[Source](http://barendgehrels.blogspot.com/2010/10/tag-dispatching-by-type-tag-dispatching.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can just use `std::enable_if`:

```
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
        return t;
}

template<class T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_integral<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
int64_t to_int64t( const T& t )
{
        return t.to_int64t();
}
```

Comment: I think it's a better implementation than the accepted one? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Agreed. And yes, it works very nicely with both VC++ on Windows and Clang on MacOS